# Server to Server communication with IBM SBT

Tags: java, connection, ibm-sbt

I would  like to use the IBM SBT for server to server communication instead of displaying data from , for instance, connections at the user. In this particular usecase I would like to have data updated in Connections whenever a user saves or edits data.

Because we are not using oAuth we would like to use Basic authentication without prompting the user for authentication. Are there any examples how to do is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there are some examples of using Pure Java, no J2EE.

http://bastide.org/2014/01/28/how-to-develop-a-simple-java-integration-with-the-ibm-social-business-toolkit-sdk/

and

https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK/blob/master/samples/java/sbt.sample.app/src/com/ibm/sbt/sample/app/BlogServiceApp.java

Essentially, you'll need the dependent jar files.

once, you have the jar files you need to configure your class so you can get an Endpoint

once you have the endpoint you can use the endpoint in one of the top level services such 
as ForumsService

then you can use the ForumsService to call back to Connections